# Javascript (Node.js) - Refactoring a long function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, coding-style, refactoring

I have a function, which is associated with a specific concept "Notifications".

After creating a module "Notifications.js", I have written the following:

```
function Notifications() {} // No constructor...

Notifications.sendPushNotification = async function (
  title,
  body,
  data,
  badge = undefined,
  sound = "default",
  pushNotificationsTokens
) {
    // Part 1 - 6 lines

    // Part 2 - 10 lines
    
    // Part 3 - 20 lines
}

module.exports(Notifications);
```

Then, I have also thought to make the code better by doing:

```
Notifications.sendPushNotification = async function (
  title,
  body,
  data,
  badge = undefined,
  sound = "default",
  pushNotificationsTokens
) {
    part1();
    part2();
    part3();

    function part1() {
       // 6 lines
    }

    function part2() {
       // 10 lines
    }
    
    function part3() {
       // 20 lines
    }
}

module.exports(Notifications);
```

Here, another question comes to my mind:

Is it a style of code to create classes in independent modules even though they only have static methods?
I have seen some GitHub repositories where different developers do this. But... why? Is this way associated to a programming methodology like DDD or something? Is there a difference between doing the code above and this code?

*notifications.js*

```
exports.sendPushNotification = async function (
  title,
  body,
  data,
  badge = undefined,
  sound = "default",
  pushNotificationsTokens
) {
    part1();
    part2();
    part3();

    function part1() {
       // 6 lines
    }

    function part2() {
       // 10 lines
    }
    
    function part3() {
       // 20 lines
    }
}
```

Also, is there a better way to refactor this function? For example, some professional way to pass long list of arguments, using shorter names, or something like that.

Comment: This question is the definition of _software engineering_. It's not really possible to say anything in general because it always depends on the specific case. A long function, or a function with many arguments is an indication that it might be doing too much. Whether you want to do something about it depends on how complicated it is, how important it is, how much time you have, etc.

Comment: And what about the definition of a class without constructor which only have an static method, instead of just exporting a function?

Comment: A static class method and a function are equivalent. There might be legacy (or future) reasons why it is that way. Maybe there were (or will be) related functions and it might be nice to have them together in a class. This is also a little bit personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a good practice to keep your code refactored. I often use async module to handle my async functions. You can find the module at https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/. If these functions are not async and your functions are dependent on variables. You should use the below strategy for refactoring. This is just a suggestion which I follow.

```
exports.sendPushNotification = async function (
  title,
  body,
  data,
  badge = undefined,
  sound = "default",
  pushNotificationsTokens
) {
    let var1 = part1(title);
    let var2 = part2(body, var1);
    let var3 = part3(var1, var2);
    
    // ...do some calculations
}


function part1(title) {
   // 6 lines
}

function part2(body, param1) {
   // 10 lines
}

function part3(param1, param2) {
   // 20 lines
}
```